# Lookup the accountnumber rather than name in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, lookup

Can I use the accountnumber to search in lookup rather than name in visualforce page? Is this possible? Thoughts please. Here is the code

```
 <apex:InputField label="Group Name" value="{!tskrec.Account_Lookup__c}"/>
```

[image]

Here instead of name can I able to search using Account Number? Since this is a standard functionality I came to know this can't be done by using Out of box. Can I try with the customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Enhanced lookup to search based on other field except Name.

1. From Setup, enter Search Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Search Settings.
2. In the Lookup Settings area, select the objects for which you want to enable enhanced lookup functionality.
3. Click Save.

[Enable Enhanced Lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm&type=0)